# Trying to build my first hello-world app with kivy with buildozer- error permission denied?

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I had the idea to start doing some apps with python for quite some time, so yesterday I thought to give Kivy a try. My system is a Ubuntu 16.04.2-version, and I followed the tutorial here https://www.digitaljunky.io/make-a-snake-game-for-android-written-in-python-part-1/ to download all the necessary packages. Unfortunately I am not able to get the simple 'hello-word-app' as described in that tutorial (and many others) running with buildozer. It shows the following error (just showing the last few lines, if you need more just tell me!):

```
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 149):
                        (Py_ssize_t)ctx->fmt_offset, (Py_ssize_t)offset);   
                    ^   
jnius/jnius.c:44574:20: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 4 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]  
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate':    
jnius/jnius.c:44815:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=] 
       dtype->name, (Py_ssize_t)dtype->size, (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : ""); 
       ^    
jnius/jnius.c:44815:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 6 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]   
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ValidateAndInit_memviewslice':    
jnius/jnius.c:48006:22: warning: format '%zu' expects argument of type 'size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]   
                      (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : "");    
                      ^ 
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__pyx_f_5jnius_5jnius_convert_python_to_jobject':   
jnius/jnius.c:10495:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retmidinit' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]    
   __pyx_v_retobject = (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->NewObjectA(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_retclass, __pyx_v_retmidinit, __pyx_v_j_ret);  
                     ^  
jnius/jnius.c:10495:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retclass' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]  
/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project android app/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/tools/liblink.sh -lm -L/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/libs_collections/myapp -L/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/anja/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o -Llibs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install/lib -lSDL2 -llog -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.so   
unable to execute /home/anja/Schreibtisch/project: Permission denied    
error: command '/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius && /home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/anja/Schreibtisch/project/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,python2 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/anja/Schreibtisch/project android app/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

This is the end of the buildozer output with the log_level=2, but the errors don't tell me anything. The permission denied might hint at a write/read problem, but giving read/write permissions to all users for that folder had no effect whatsoever. Any ideas where the problem lies? I also looked on overstack but couldn't find an answer to my problem... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't see what might be wrong here - it's as if /home/anja/Schreibtisch/project isn't marked executable, but presumably it is? Do you get exactly the same error if you copy the project to a differently-named folder?

Comment: provide some more logs from where the error start

Comment: Okay, I feel really, really stupid now. Just moved the project to my home folder, and bim, it works. Rarely been so happy to see a simple 'hello world' widget pop up! Thank you very much!